# When i am using Audiorecord function,some music app is still playing.why?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager

i am facing a problem. when i am using Audiorecord function,some music App is still playing and some gets pause immediately. 
i've used the mAudioManager.requestAudioFocus() and also use mAudioManager.abandonAudioFocus(). but it seems doesn't always useful in some situation.
is there another method to solve this problem?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there's nothing forcing an app to respect the current audio focus. In other words, other apps are free to ignore the fact that your app currently has the audio focus.

Comment: but i request the focus and i'v gotten the focus.but some music app is still playing. whether the focus is singleton or not? and Would u mind telling me that your method if u are facing this problem? thanks~

Comment: I've never attempted to solve such a problem, so I wouldn't know. My point was that the loss of audio focus is a _hint_ to apps that they should stop playback, but there's nothing _forcing_ them to stop playback (to my knowledge at least).